# Three dice are thrown. What is the probability the same number appears on exactly two of the three dice?

Tags: probability

This is my solution, not sure if this is correct.

Let D1, D2, D3 be the outcome of the three dice.

Since "exactly 2 of the 3 dice" is mentioned, I have the following sets:

```
(D1 = D2)AND(D1 =/= D3)
```

Hence the probability of such an occurance is:

```
P((D1 = D2)AND(D1 =/= D3)) = P(D1=D2)*P(D1=/=D3)
```

This is because D1=/=D3 is independent of whether D1=D2. Hence the probability is:

```
P((D1 = D2)AND(D1 =/= D3)) = (1/6)*(5/6) = (5/36)
```

I don't know if what I'm doing is right or wrong, I just started with probability and my brain literally have no neural network for probabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colour the dice blue, white, and red. There are $6^3$ equally likely outcomes of the tossing.

Which two dice get the same number? They can be chosen in $\binom{3}{2}$ ways. The common number can be chosen in $6$ ways, and for each such way the other number can be chosen in $5$ ways, for a total of $\binom{3}{2}(6)(5)$. For the probability, divide by $6^3$.

**Remark:** It looks as if you went through similar reasoning, but found the probability that the blue and the white get the same number, with the red getting a different number.

We could solve the problem in other ways. For example, let us find the probability that the blue is "different" but white and red are the same. Whatever blue got, the probability white is different is $\frac{5}{6}$. And the probability red matches white is $\frac{1}{6}$, for a probability of $\frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{6}$.

Multiply by $3$ because any one of the dice can be the individualist.

Comment: So, let me just make it clear, what you did is use \binom{3}{2} to factor the fact that not only blue and white can get the same number.

Comment: That's right. It could also be white and red the same, blue different, or blue and red the same, white different.